# Why isn't my jquery-latest.min.js not getting loaded

Tags: jquery

These are my scripts ... and for some reason the .min.js is not getting loaded, what is the current version?

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" ></script> 
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Subsequently, I am trying to use the following

```
$.cookie('my-cookie', '1');
```

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: You need to add the http protocol to the script `src` if you're running this from local.

Comment: why are you adding jQuery twice?

Answer (score 0):

you are including jQuery twice but jQuery Cookie none.
Include it like:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
```